# What needs to be done if an editor requires "very thorough editing"?

Tags: journals, peer-review, editors, journal-workflow

> The Editor's and the reviewers' comments are as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> Eic
>
> a very thorough editing is  a must

What does the last line mean? What kinds of things do I need to do?

I think I need to check the whole manuscript for finding language problem.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably correct, the editor is asking you to check the whole manuscript for English. If you have a friend who's fluent at English you can ask him / her, otherwise you can also contact a copyediting service such as [Enago](https://www.enago.com/editing-services.htm?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIofva1dqS2QIVxhOPCh1PIQ14EAAYASAAEgL15_D_BwE) or [Editage](https://www.editage.com/editing-services/manuscript-editing.html?keyword=english%20editing&matchtype=p&device=c&creative=230988936951&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI1NKd5tqS2QIViAMqCh0t3wOHEAAYASAAEgKJpvD_BwE) (this is not a recommendation for either service, since I have never used them before).

Good luck!

Comment: "fluent" is not enough for your (potential) friend: it's not enough to be able to speak the language easily. He/she also has to be good at grammar and spelling.

Comment: I agree with this answer, and I'd add that the editor's comment indicates (to me) that there are a great many language errors in the paper.